# How to make new line if the value contains (,) in Php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display information that contains `,` into a new line.
This the current output that I get
[current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kn2R.png) I wanted to display in by separated comma, so everytime there is comma it will automatically turn into a new line.

This is my current code

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;">Duration</td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $row ['duration']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

`duration` is the name of the column in my database.

With the code above how do I achieve this output ?

```
Monday:7am-2am,
Tuesday:7am-2am,
Wednesday:7am-2am,
Thursday:7am-2am,
Friday:7am-2am,
Saturday:7am-2am
```

instead of this

```
Monday:7am-2am,Tuesday:7am-2am,Wednesday:7am-2am,Thursday:7am-2am,Friday:7am-2am,Saturday:7am-2am
```

Comment: Does it have to be in PHP and not Javascript?

Comment: I'm exploring any options that will make it works

Comment: There are many ways to depend on you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;">Duration</td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo str_replace(',',",\n",$row ['duration']); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ok I just change `<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo str_replace(',',",\n",$row ['duration']); ?></td>` into `<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo str_replace(',',",<br>",$row ['duration']); ?></td>` now it works like what i wanted to achieved. thank you sir

Comment: I replace the `,/n` into `,<br>`

Comment: I tested it on my system and it was correct! It is not a problem why you voted negative :)

Comment: I said the easiest way, but there are different models.